# Categorie parents and childs displayed

Tags: categories

I'm trying to create a menu directly hard-coded, basically I need to display the parent category and below its child categories, however I have to do this several times meaning something like this:

  Category 1

category child of 1.1

category child of 1.2

category child of 1.3

  Category 2

category child of 2.1

category child of 2.2

and so on....

I've tried whit different kinds functions like call the category and is subcategory to call its ancestor, however I haven't been able to get the result I'm looking for.

Any suggestion??? Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
wp_list_categories( array('depth'=>2,'title_li'=>null));
```

This outputs the categories as a list, with their children as a nested list. The categories are linked to their respective page.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, thanks a lot Stephen

Answer (score 1):

use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) with the 'parent' parameter to get only top level categories; the use a foreach loop to loop through these categories, and use the 'parent' parameter or the 'child_of' parameter.
depending on your formatting requiements, this might also work with [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)